# Visual Studio clear a text file

Tags: c#, file, visual-studio-2010, text

I want to be able to click a picture box that will clear a text files text not delete the text file but just remove the text inside sort of like resetting it. I want the picture box to work as a delete button pretty much. I can save text into the file and read it I just want to clear its contents.

```
StreamReader script = new StreamReader(@"tasks\task1.txt"); //locates task1
        script == null;
```

That is sort of what I have but this does not work

Answer (score 3):

Simply Use [`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
File.WriteAllText("yourFile.txt", "");
```

This will erase all the text in the text file and replace it with empty string and you will end up with a 0 byte file.

[File.WriteAllText Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then
>   closes the file. **If the target file already exists, it is
>   overwritten**.

Comment: For some reason this did not work the text in my files still remand the same

Answer (score 1):

Try [File.WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like this:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"tasks\task1.txt", "");
```